# Анимированное открытие страницы при переходе по ссылке?

Tags: css, css-animation

Подскажите решение на css: клик по ссылке анимированно-плавно открывает и выводит страницу снизу окна монитора. Отлично если будет ссылка на пример кода подобной реализации, возможно есть готовые css библиотеки.

Comment: разве что можно , повесить на body{opacity:0;} а пр загрузке страницы менять это значение ... 

на css это сделать нельзя - css не знает события браузера onload , onclick и т д ....

Comment: body{opacity:0;} – так не пойдёт. Есть ли какая-нибудь простая грамотейная js бибилотечка?

Comment: для боди - это условно - скрыть и показать мы можем любой блок

Comment: Да, это понятно. Просто нужно чтоб было сделан грамотейно, эффектно.

Comment: если до субботы ни сделают - я разберусь - как в тот раз

Comment: Почему именно до субботы? :)

Comment: потому что я работаю - только в субботу выходной, мою почту помнишь же ?

Comment: Понял. Почту помню конечно. Если к тому времени задачу решу, дам знать, чтобы тебе зря не заморачиваться. Тебе как удобней на почту или сюда?

Comment: но почту пиши - если не справишся - то я рискну